# React JS onClick method not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS and am just picking it up. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>React - Component</title>
<script src="../../js/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  var Comment= React.createClass({
    edit:function(){
        alert('Editing comment');
      },
    remove:function(){
        alert('Remove comment');
      },
    render:function(){
      return(
        <div classname="commentContainer">
         <div classname="commentText">Whatever</div>
            <button classname="button-primary" onclick={this.edit}>Edit</button>
            <button classname="button-danger" onclick={this.remove}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
  <div classname="board">
    <Comment>LOL</Comment>
  </div>,
   document.getElementById('container')
  );
</script>
```

When I click the edit/ delete buttons in the browser they do not show the alert dialog. What am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: Perhaps it should be `onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}`? You getting any errors?

Comment: onclick ==> onClick

Comment: I think you have the wrong casing for onClick, you need to have a capital C like onClick={this.edit}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**React event handlers need to be in camelCase:** onClick (Notice the capital 'C')

Comment: Works fine now thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should use onClick instead onclick. See the working code below.

Read more about handling events in react [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

```js
  var Comment= React.createClass({
    edit:function(){
        alert('Editing comment');
      },
    remove:function(){
        alert('Remove comment');
      },
    render:function(){
      return(
        <div classname="commentContainer">
         <div classname="commentText">Whatever</div>
            <button classname="button-primary" onClick={this.edit}>Edit</button>
            <button classname="button-danger" onClick={this.remove}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
  <div classname="board">
    <Comment>LOL</Comment>
  </div>,
   document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>React - Component</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
```